# Serving a default image with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following configuration in nginx:

```
  location /static/ {
       root /srv/kose/;
       expires 2w;
       access_log off;
 }


 location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8089;
```

}

If a file is not found in /static/, I want to serve a default image, and *not* proxy_pass to 8089. Currently, it looks for the file in the root for static, if it cannot find it, it tries the proxy.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work. How can I tell nginx to serve the default image? I have also tried `try_files` to no avail.

```
  location /static/ {
       root /srv/kose/;
       expires 2w;
       access_log off;
       error_page 404 /srv/static/defaultimage.jpg;
 }


 location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8089;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
 location /static/ {
       root /srv/kose/;
       expires 2w;
       access_log off;
       try_files $uri /static/img/yazar/authornoimage.jpg;

 }
```

Note that instead of the file location, I had to write the URL of the default image for try_files.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is bad way because status will be 200 and this image will be indexed endlessly by search engines. Moreover catch-all techniques are rather penalized by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

```
location /static/ {
    root /srv/kose;
    expires 2w;
    access_log off;
    error_page =200 /defaultimage.jpg;
}

location = /defaultimage.jpg {
    internal;
    root /srv/static;
    expires 2w;
    access_log off;
}
```

or

```
location /static/ {
    root /srv;
    expires 2w;
    access_log off;
    try_files /kose$uri /static/defaultimage.jpg =404;
}
```